# How do I get my two codes to work so that the D3 works all the time

Tags: php, json, html, d3.js, raspberry-pi

so to start off I have an index.php with html loading a d3 liquid gauge. I can load this in a browser with a static integer placed into the code and it works. I have a second file called  Tdata.php that query MySQL and returns the table in a Json echo. This can be displayed in the browser as 
[{"temperature":"70","Tdate":"2017-05-29 05:04:56"}]. 
Each peace works separately but when I the enter my D3.json so that the current reading displays in the gauge the page goes blank. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated as I feel like a noob when it comes to D3. Even after spending day on http://www.d3noob.org/2012/12/getting-data.html.
I have even tried to use tsv file with the same outcome.

index.php

```html
 <?php
$username = "root";
$password = "1cookie";
$server = "localhost";
$database = "environment";

 $server = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password);
 $connection = mysql_select_db($database, $server);


 $myHquery = "SELECT * FROM `AirHumidity` WHERE `Hdate`  ORDER BY Hdate DESC LIMIT 1";
 $Hquery = mysql_query($myHquery);
    if ( ! $Hquery ) {
        echo mysql_error();
        die;    }
    $Hdata = array();
    
    for ($x = 0; $x < mysql_num_rows($Hquery); $x++) {
        $Hdata[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($Hquery);
    }
     
     
echo $json_data = json_encode($Hdata);     
     
    mysql_close($server);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

 


<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        .liquidFillGaugeText { font-family: Helvetica; font-weight: bold; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<svg id="fillgauge1" width="97%" height="250"></svg>

<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="liquidFillGauge.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 
 
 <?php echo "data=".$json_data.";"?>
 
 
  d3.json("data=", function(data, error) {
           data.forEach(function(d) 
              {d.Hdate = parseDate(d.Hdate);
              d.humidity = +d.humidity;}
         )});

 
 d3.select("#fillgauge1").call(d3.liquidfillgauge, 69);
      
   
 

   
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

LiquidFillGuage.js

```js
/*!
 * @license Open source under BSD 2-clause (http://choosealicense.com/licenses/bsd-2-clause/)
 * Copyright (c) 2015, Curtis Bratton
 * All rights reserved.
 */
(function(d3) {
    var idGenerator = (function() {
        var count = 0;
        return function(prefix) {
            return prefix + "-" + count++;
        };
    })();

    var defaultConfig = {
        // Values
        minValue: 0, // The gauge minimum value.
        maxValue: 100, // The gauge maximum value.

        // Styles
        circleThickness: 0.05, // The outer circle thickness as a percentage of it's radius.
        circleFillGap: 0.05, // The size of the gap between the outer circle and wave circle as a percentage of the outer circles radius.
        circleColor: "#178BCA", // The color of the outer circle.
        backgroundColor: null, // The color of the background
        waveColor: "#178BCA", // The color of the fill wave.
        width: 0, // You might want to set the width and height if it is not detected properly by the plugin
        height: 0,

        // Waves
        waveHeight: 0.05, // The wave height as a percentage of the radius of the wave circle.
        waveCount: 1, // The number of full waves per width of the wave circle.
        waveOffset: 0, // The amount to initially offset the wave. 0 = no offset. 1 = offset of one full wave.

        // Animations
        waveRise: true, // Control if the wave should rise from 0 to it's full height, or start at it's full height.
        waveRiseTime: 1000, // The amount of time in milliseconds for the wave to rise from 0 to it's final height.
        waveRiseAtStart: true, // If set to false and waveRise at true, will disable only the initial animation
        waveAnimate: true, // Controls if the wave scrolls or is static.
        waveAnimateTime: 18000, // The amount of time in milliseconds for a full wave to enter the wave circle.
        waveHeightScaling: true, // Controls wave size scaling at low and high fill percentages. When true, wave height reaches it's maximum at 50% fill, and minimum at 0% and 100% fill. This helps to prevent the wave from making the wave circle from appear totally full or empty when near it's minimum or maximum fill.
        valueCountUp: true, // If true, the displayed value counts up from 0 to it's final value upon loading and updating. If false, the final value is displayed.
        valueCountUpAtStart: true, // If set to false and valueCountUp at true, will disable only the initial animation

        // Text
        textVertPosition: 0.5, // The height at which to display the percentage text withing the wave circle. 0 = bottom, 1 = top.
        textSize: 1, // The relative height of the text to display in the wave circle. 1 = 50%
        displayPercent: true, // If true, a % symbol is displayed after the value.
        textColor: "#045681", // The color of the value text when the wave does not overlap it.
        waveTextColor: "#A4DBf8", // The color of the value text when the wave overlaps it.
    };

    d3.liquidfillgauge = function(g, value, settings) {
        // Handle configuration
        var config = d3.map(defaultConfig);
        d3.map(settings).forEach(function(key, val) {
            config.set(key, val);
        });

        g.each(function(d) {
            var gauge = d3.select(this);

            var width = config.get("width") !== 0 ? config.get("width") : parseInt(gauge.style("width"));
            var height = config.get("height") !== 0 ? config.get("height") : parseInt(gauge.style("height"));
            var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;
            var locationX = width / 2 - radius;
            var locationY = height / 2 - radius;
            var fillPercent = Math.max(config.get("minValue"), Math.min(config.get("maxValue"), value)) / config.get("maxValue");

            var waveHeightScale;
            if (config.get("waveHeightScaling")) {
                waveHeightScale = d3.scale.linear()
                    .range([0, config.get("waveHeight"), 0])
                    .domain([0, 50, 100]);
            } else {
                waveHeightScale = d3.scale.linear()
                    .range([config.get("waveHeight"), config.get("waveHeight")])
                    .domain([0, 100]);
            }

            var textPixels = (config.get("textSize") * radius / 2);
            var textFinalValue = parseFloat(value).toFixed(2);
            var textStartValue = config.get("valueCountUp") ? config.get("minValue") : textFinalValue;
            var percentText = config.get("displayPercent") ? "%" : "";
            var circleThickness = config.get("circleThickness") * radius;
            var circleFillGap = config.get("circleFillGap") * radius;
            var fillCircleMargin = circleThickness + circleFillGap;
            var fillCircleRadius = radius - fillCircleMargin;
            var waveHeight = fillCircleRadius * waveHeightScale(fillPercent * 100);

            var waveLength = fillCircleRadius * 2 / config.get("waveCount");
            var waveClipCount = 1 + config.get("waveCount");
            var waveClipWidth = waveLength * waveClipCount;

            // Rounding functions so that the correct number of decimal places is always displayed as the value counts up.
            var textRounder = function(value) {
                return Math.round(value);
            };
            if (parseFloat(textFinalValue) != parseFloat(textRounder(textFinalValue))) {
                textRounder = function(value) {
                    return parseFloat(value).toFixed(1);
                };
            }
            if (parseFloat(textFinalValue) != parseFloat(textRounder(textFinalValue))) {
                textRounder = function(value) {
                    return parseFloat(value).toFixed(2);
                };
            }

            // Data for building the clip wave area.
            var data = [];
            for (var i = 0; i <= 40 * waveClipCount; i++) {
                data.push({
                    x: i / (40 * waveClipCount),
                    y: (i / (40))
                });
            }

            // Scales for drawing the outer circle.
            var gaugeCircleX = d3.scale.linear().range([0, 2 * Math.PI]).domain([0, 1]);
            var gaugeCircleY = d3.scale.linear().range([0, radius]).domain([0, radius]);

            // Scales for controlling the size of the clipping path.
            var waveScaleX = d3.scale.linear().range([0, waveClipWidth]).domain([0, 1]);
            var waveScaleY = d3.scale.linear().range([0, waveHeight]).domain([0, 1]);

            // Scales for controlling the position of the clipping path.
            var waveRiseScale = d3.scale.linear()
                // The clipping area size is the height of the fill circle + the wave height, so we position the clip wave
                // such that the it will won't overlap the fill circle at all when at 0%, and will totally cover the fill
                // circle at 100%.
                .range([(fillCircleMargin + fillCircleRadius * 2 + waveHeight), (fillCircleMargin - waveHeight)])
                .domain([0, 1]);
            var waveAnimateScale = d3.scale.linear()
                .range([0, waveClipWidth - fillCircleRadius * 2]) // Push the clip area one full wave then snap back.
                .domain([0, 1]);

            // Scale for controlling the position of the text within the gauge.
            var textRiseScaleY = d3.scale.linear()
                .range([fillCircleMargin + fillCircleRadius * 2, (fillCircleMargin + textPixels * 0.7)])
                .domain([0, 1]);

            // Center the gauge within the parent SVG.
            var gaugeGroup = gauge.append("g")
                .attr('transform', 'translate(' + locationX + ',' + locationY + ')');

            // Draw the background circle
            if (config.get("backgroundColor")) {
                gaugeGroup.append("circle")
                    .attr("r", radius)
                    .style("fill", config.get("backgroundColor"))
                    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + radius + ',' + radius + ')');
            }

            // Draw the outer circle.
            var gaugeCircleArc = d3.svg.arc()
                .startAngle(gaugeCircleX(0))
                .endAngle(gaugeCircleX(1))
                .outerRadius(gaugeCircleY(radius))
                .innerRadius(gaugeCircleY(radius - circleThickness));
            gaugeGroup.append("path")
                .attr("d", gaugeCircleArc)
                .style("fill", config.get("circleColor"))
                .attr('transform', 'translate(' + radius + ',' + radius + ')');

            // Text where the wave does not overlap.
            var text1 = gaugeGroup.append("text")
                .attr("class", "liquidFillGaugeText")
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .attr("font-size", textPixels + "px")
                .style("fill", config.get("textColor"))
                .attr('transform', 'translate(' + radius + ',' + textRiseScaleY(config.get("textVertPosition")) + ')');

            // The clipping wave area.
            var clipArea = d3.svg.area()
                .x(function(d) {
                    return waveScaleX(d.x);
                })
                .y0(function(d) {
                    return waveScaleY(Math.sin(Math.PI * 2 * config.get("waveOffset") * -1 + Math.PI * 2 * (1 - config.get("waveCount")) + d.y * 2 * Math.PI));
                })
                .y1(function(d) {
                    return (fillCircleRadius * 2 + waveHeight);
                });
            var clipId = idGenerator("clipWave");
            var waveGroup = gaugeGroup.append("defs")
                .append("clipPath")
                .attr("id", clipId);
            var wave = waveGroup.append("path")
                .datum(data)
                .attr("d", clipArea);

            // The inner circle with the clipping wave attached.
            var fillCircleGroup = gaugeGroup.append("g")
                .attr("clip-path", "url(#" + clipId + ")");
            fillCircleGroup.append("circle")
                .attr("cx", radius)
                .attr("cy", radius)
                .attr("r", fillCircleRadius)
                .style("fill", config.get("waveColor"));

            // Text where the wave does overlap.
            var text2 = fillCircleGroup.append("text")
                .attr("class", "liquidFillGaugeText")
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .attr("font-size", textPixels + "px")
                .style("fill", config.get("waveTextColor"))
                .attr('transform', 'translate(' + radius + ',' + textRiseScaleY(config.get("textVertPosition")) + ')');

            // Make the wave rise. wave and waveGroup are separate so that horizontal and vertical movement can be controlled independently.
            var waveGroupXPosition = fillCircleMargin + fillCircleRadius * 2 - waveClipWidth;

            if (config.get("waveAnimate")) {
                var animateWave = function() {
                    wave.transition()
                        .duration(config.get("waveAnimateTime"))
                        .ease("linear")
                        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + waveAnimateScale(1) + ',0)')
                        .each("end", function() {
                            wave.attr('transform', 'translate(' + waveAnimateScale(0) + ',0)');
                            animateWave();
                        });
                };
                animateWave();
            }

            var transition = function(from, to, riseWave, animateText) {
              // Update texts and animate
              if (animateText) {
                  var textTween = function() {
                      var i = d3.interpolate(from, to);
                      return function(t) {
                          this.textContent = textRounder(i(t)) + percentText;
                      };
                  };
                  text1.transition()
                      .duration(config.get("waveRiseTime"))
                      .tween("text", textTween);
                  text2.transition()
                      .duration(config.get("waveRiseTime"))
                      .tween("text", textTween);
              } else {
                    text1.text(textRounder(to) + percentText);
                    text2.text(textRounder(to) + percentText);
              }

              // Update the wave
              toPercent = Math.max(config.get("minValue"), Math.min(config.get("maxValue"), to)) / config.get("maxValue");
              fromPercent = Math.max(config.get("minValue"), Math.min(config.get("maxValue"), from)) / config.get("maxValue");

              if (riseWave) {
                  waveGroup.attr('transform', 'translate(' + waveGroupXPosition + ',' + waveRiseScale(fromPercent) + ')')
                      .transition()
                      .duration(config.get("waveRiseTime"))
                      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + waveGroupXPosition + ',' + waveRiseScale(toPercent) + ')');
              } else {
                  waveGroup.attr('transform', 'translate(' + waveGroupXPosition + ',' + waveRiseScale(toPercent) + ')');
              }
            };

            transition(
              textStartValue,
              textFinalValue,
              config.get("waveRise") && config.get("waveRiseAtStart"),
              config.get("valueCountUp") && config.get("valueCountUpAtStart")
            );

            // Event to update the value
            gauge.on("valueChanged", function(newValue) {
              transition(value, newValue, config.get("waveRise"), config.get("valueCountUp"));
              value = newValue;
            });

            gauge.on("destroy", function() {
              // Stop all the transitions
              text1.interrupt().transition();
              text2.interrupt().transition();
              waveGroup.interrupt().transition();
              wave.interrupt().transition();

              // Unattach events
              gauge.on("valueChanged", null);
              gauge.on("destroy", null);
            });
        });
    };
})(d3);
```

Comment: So after reviewing the code I found the missing php in the body of the html that injects the string, along with changing it back into dtg and integer for the d3. I can get both to display in the same page but debugging returns the following: data.forEach is not a function. All in All I've made a little Progress.

Comment: It could be that your data is not loaded by the time you are calling it? You should probably check that all data is loaded before you run the chart script (async).

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to resolve the issue by adding the following after the php echo.

```html
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S").parse;
     
      d3.json("data=", function(Hdata, error) {
   d3.json("data=", function(data, error) {            data.forEach(function(d) {
            data.forEach(function(d)                 d.humidity = +d.humidity; 
               {d.Hdate = parseDate(d.Hdate);                d.Hdate = parseDate(d.Hdate);
               d.humidity = +d.humidity;}               
          )});   
               
      d3.select("#fillgauge1").call(d3.liquidfillgauge, d.humidity,{
         circleThickness: 0.15,
         circleColor: "#0b4cc4",
         textColor: "#ef980b",
         waveTextColor: "#e05611",
         waveColor: "#5d27db",
         textVertPosition: 0.5,
         waveAnimateTime: 1000,
         waveHeight: 0.05,
         waveAnimate: true,
         waveRise: false,
         waveOffset: 0.25,
         textSize: 0.75,
         waveCount: 3
       });       
  d3.select("#fillgauge1").call(d3.liquidfillgauge, 69);          
    })});
```

Now if I could only hide the echo from displaying in the body of the webpage and only in the d3 gauge and auto refresh anytime a new table is created.
Any suggestions on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.